# Ionic native page transition doesnt work

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

i´m new using ionic and i want to change the page transition from page to page.

```
    import { NativePageTransitions, NativeTransitionOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-page-transitions';
    import { CategoryPage } from '../category/category';

      constructor(
        private nativePageTransitions: NativePageTransitions
      ) {
      }

      public pushPage(category) {
        let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
          direction: 'left',
          duration: 600,
          slowdownfactor: 3,
          iosdelay: 60
        };
        this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
        this.navCtrl.push(CategoryPage, { data: category });
      }
```

but for some reason is not working, i  mean  there is not error or something just does not apply the transition, any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a **Native plugin** you must test this on a **Device**.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

Or

```
ionic cordova run ios --prod --device
```